# Creating Multiple li on multiple ol and put them in specific position

Tags: javascript, html-lists, appendchild

I'm sorry about my bad English, I'm learning js hope you can help me =)

What I want is to create a `li` element on both `ol` with JS and put them in the second position in the list, when I do for the 1 `ol` it works, but when I attempt to put it into a loop (`for`), it's not working =(
I'm pretty noob at this, if you can help me I will appreciate it a lot thanks

```js
for (i = 0; i > 1; i++) {
  var newelementlist = document.createElement("li");
  var newcontent = document.createTextNode("Element N3");
  newelementlist.appendChild(newcontent);

  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[i];
  var lastson = container.lastElementChild;
  container.appendChild(newelementlist);
  container.insertBefore(newelementlist, lastson);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Element N1</li>
    <li>Element N2</li>
  </ol>
  <br>
  <ol class="list">
    <li>Element N1</li>
    <li>Element N2</li>
  </ol>
  <br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, maybe is it of that you need:

```js
let ols = [...document.querySelectorAll('ol.list')]; // get all <ol class="list">
ols.forEach(ol => { // iterate...
    let lis = [...ol.querySelectorAll('li')]; // get all <li> child
  lis.forEach(li => ol.removeChild(li)); // iterate to remove from <ol> parent
  let newLi = document.createElement("li"); // create your new <li>
  let newContent = document.createTextNode('New Element'); // create new content for new <li>
  newLi.appendChild(newContent); // append the content into new <li>
    lis.splice(1, 0, newLi); // add the new <li> at the second position in array (index 1)
  lis.forEach(li => ol.appendChild(li)); // append all <li> on current <ol>
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
      <ol class="list">
        <li>Element N1</li>
        <li>Element N2</li>
      </ol>
      <br>
      <ol class="list">
        <li>Element N1</li>
        <li>Element N2</li>
      </ol>
      <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavoAdolfo/3u496y0v/19/

Comment: really thanks for the help, actually im not using jquery so i dont know hehe, what i want is the list get something like this
    1.Element N1
    2.Element N3
    3.Element N2
im using js to make it to both ol from HTML

Comment: So... this example don't use jQuery.

Comment: oh im sorry, i see query word, im really sorry i will test it thx

Answer (score 1):

To append a DOM element to a specific position, you can use `insertBefore` :

`parent.insertBefore(newElement, parent.children[i])`

Where `i` is the position of the next element. In your case, the parent is one `ol` element and children are its `li` elements. You want to insert an element at the second position so `i` is `2`.

To apply this to every `ol`, just make a loop on every parent element you have with your selection by class.